# How to remove file logicaly?

Tags: 12.04, filesystem

I have a file on my computer which was called `just one.flv` , I deleted this file but the problem here is that the icon of the file still appeared and when I try to do any operation on it from terminal , this message appeared  `No Such file or directory`.

Now I can't do any operation on it. I can't copy or rename or cut or delete.

I tried:

```
rm -f 'just one.flv'
```

to force delete.

Any help?

Comment: Where was the file located, and where does the icon appear?

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the space;

```
rm just\ one.flv
```

No flag needed for this file.